# Numba decreases performance on simple for-loop function

Tags: python, numpy, numba, adjacency-matrix

I'm working with relatively large datasets (100,000+ elements) and need to create an adjacency matrix for these.

I've written a very basic for loop that accomplishes this for a given of connected nodes (nx2)

```
nodes = np.random.randint(20000, size=(20000, 2))

def adjMat(node_list):
    n = np.max(node_list)
    A = np.zeros((n, n))
    for tail, head in node_list:
        A[tail-1, head-1] = 1
    return A
```

This works fine and isn't as slow as I thought it would be, but assumed I could significantly improve performance by using numba for this super simple function.

So I've added two jitted functions (one using parallel) to see the performance difference. I've also just included networkx to see if that's well optimised.

```
@njit()
def adjMat_numba(node_list):
    n = np.max(node_list)
    A = np.zeros((n, n))
    for tail, head in node_list:
        A[tail-1, head-1] = 1
    return A

@njit(parallel = True)
def adjMat_numba_para(node_list):
    n = np.max(node_list)
    A = np.zeros((n, n))
    for tail, head in node_list:
        A[tail-1, head-1] = 1
    return A

def getAdjacenyList(node_list):
    G = nx.Graph([e for e in node_list])
    A = nx.convert.to_dict_of_lists(G)

    return A
```

Here's the output for my test on 20000 pairs of connected nodes:

```
%timeit a = adjMat(nodes)
112 ms ± 3.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit b = adjMat_numba(nodes)
1.34 s ± 41.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit c = adjMat_numba_para(nodes)
251 ms ± 3.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit d = getAdjacenyList(nodes)
149 ms ± 3.31 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

I'm incredibly surprised that using numba actually makes the function several times slower and that even in parallel mode, it's still not as quick as for loop. Numba also seems to use significantly more memory than the for loop. Also, I'm pretty surprised that that networkx is slower than the for loop - I would have expected that a library whose sole purpose was to deal with this kind of problem would be quicker.

Have I got something wrong with the numba decorator? Are there any better options to this creating an adjacency matrix quickly and efficiently?

I'm running these tests on a 12 core linux desktop, using pycharm.

Comment: `numba` takes time to initialize and compile, run those functions twice and check the times of the second run for each. If it's only being run once you might be better off without it indeed.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [22]: node_list = np.array([[0,1],[1,4],[4,2],[2,0]])                                                                                                                                     

In [27]: adjMat(node_list+1)                                                                         
Out[27]: 
array([[0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.]])
```

A non-iterative numpy approach:

```
In [28]: res = np.zeros((5,5))                                                                       
In [29]: res[node_list[0],node_list[1]] = 1                                                          
In [30]: res                                                                                         
Out[30]: 
array([[0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Does this really need `numba`?